# Timer in Windows Service .. Will this scale OK? Will threading issues occur? Is this bad practice?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, windows-services

I'm interested to know what concerns I should have about this approach. The code will be checking a SQL table for scheduled work to do and I'll change the timer to do nothing until the work is complete. Is a SQL Trigger a viable option? What about Console App on a Windows Schedule?

---

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
   this.workChecker = new Timer(new TimerCallback(DoWork), null, 0, 60*10*1000); // 10 minutes
   Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any *particular* issue? Stack Overflow is not a discussion board.

Comment: yes. i revised my question in light of your comment however I believe I've been reading discussions on here for well over a decade now.. bout time i get some 'rep' i suppose.  thnx

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't block `OnStart` so `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);` isn't needed. The timer option may work but as you can see there are some reentrancy issues (you should be sure that new job doesn't start while previous is working in order to avoid race conditions). I'd suggest to check [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) library which solves such issues out of box and has lot of other functionality for scheduled jobs.

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you very much.. I'm definitely checking out Quartz. I blocked the thread because the timer ceases to execute without it. I'm moving code to an instanced object now, maybe i could/should spawn a thread for this..?

Comment: I was running without the Service Base if interactive (for debugging etc), this why the thread was finishing with out some OnStop signal, hence the manual thread sleeping. thnx again !